# Send mail with malgun api php

Tags: php, email, mailgun

everyone.

How to correctly send mail trough mailgun API service?

Trying this way:

```
$name = strip_tags(htmlspecialchars($_POST['name']));
$phone = strip_tags(htmlspecialchars($_POST['phone']));

// mailgun
function send_mailgun($email){
    $config = array();
    $config['api_key'] = "key-32312312-12312312312-8";
    $config['api_url'] = "https://api.mailgun.net/v3/domain.com/messages";
    $message = array();
    $message['from'] = "test@gmail.com";
    $message['to'] = $email;
    $message['subject'] = "Eye-Catching Subject Line";
    $ch = curl_init();

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $config['api_url']);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH, CURLAUTH_BASIC);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD, "api:{$config['api_key']}");
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 10);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true); 
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,$message);
    $result = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);
    return $result;
}


send_mailgun('test@gmail.com');
```

However, it doesn't work. Not sending the email at all. What is the easiest/fastest way to use Mailgun with php to send simple form submission values?

Comment: What's the output? Do you get an error?

Comment: I think `text` or `html` is required.  You could also consider using their (PHP client)[https://github.com/mailgun/mailgun-php].